# mostrar una alerta después de un insert

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo un proyecto donde hago un insert y quiero mostrar una alerta con Sweet Alert, pero no me sale nada, si alguien sabe porque o como se hace?.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
<head>
    <link href="../../library/bootstrap-sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../../library/bootstrap-sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php
$c = ("INSERT INTO usuarios(Tió,Identificacion,Nombre,Nombreusu) VALUES ('$A','$B','$C','$D');");
$result = $conexion->query($c);

if ($result) {
    echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡Bien!', 'Condición cumplida', 'success');});
} else {
    echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡Error!', 'Condición no cumplida', 'warning');});
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es esto, te faltan las etiquetas de cierre de javascript

```
if ($result) {
echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡Bien!', 'Condición cumplida', 'success');});</script>";
} else {
echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡Error!', 'Condición no cumplida', 'warning');});</script>";
}
```

fijate si te funciona, porque además al abrir con comillas doble, los string que quieras mostrar dentro tienen que llevar comillas simple.

Comment: Ahh si me di cuenta de eso pero aun así no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta incluir la Biblioteca **jQuery** y el cierre de la etiqueta **script** para que funcione.

Ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<?php 
$result = 1;

if ($result == 1) {
    echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡Bien!', 'Condición cumplida', 'success');});</script>";
} else {

    echo "<script>jQuery(function(){swal('¡¡Error!', 'Condición no cumplida', 'warning');});</script>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya esta solo que no lo puse

Comment: Podrías agregar mas información sobre la estructura de tabla y conexión?

Comment: pero si me inserta lo que no me funciona es la alerta.

Comment: Esta seguro de que esta referenciando correctamente los archivos css y js?

Comment: Si están bien relacionados, por eso pregunto si algo hice mal.
Osea así como esta me saldría ya la alerta?

Answer (score 0):

Solamente tienes que agregar en el echo las librerías como se muestra a continuación:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery(function(){swal("¡Bien!", "Condición cumplida", "success");});</script>';
```